# Return Class conform to protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol that represent brand for example

I have two class in this example, Jbl and Columbo that conform to Brand protocol

The builder build some stuff and finally return the name of Jbl or Columbo class
(The build stuff is simplified with random in code sample)

In this sample code we can expect randomly Jbl Brand or Columbo Brand in the print result

But this cannot compile with error : `Protocol 'Brand' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

```swift
protocol Brand: AnyObject, Hashable {
    var name: String { get }
}

extension Brand {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}

class Jbl: Brand {
    var name: String { "Jbl" }
}

class Columbo: Brand {
    var name: String { "Columbo" }
}

class Builder {
    func build() -> Brand {    // Protocol 'Brand' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
        if .random() {
            return Jbl()
        } else {
            return Columbo()
        }
    }
}

var builder = Builder()
print(builder.build().name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for `build()` you are trying to return a type of `Brand`, but `Hashable` has `Self` requirements as part of its definition. This is why you get the error about "Self or associated type requirements".

A possible solution is to make `Brand` not `Hashable` itself, but any class which conforms to `Brand` **and** `Hashable` will get the `Hashable` implementation *for* `Brand`:

```
protocol Brand: AnyObject {
    var name: String { get }
}

extension Brand where Self: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

However, accessing `build()` will not give you a `hashValue`, since only classes which conform to `Brand` **and** `Hashable` have `hashValue`.

To fix this, conform `Jbl` and `Columbo` to the `Hashable` protocol. Then add a function like this in the `Builder` class for example:

```
func getHashValue() -> Int {
    if .random() {
        return Jbl().hashValue
    } else {
        return Columbo().hashValue
    }
}
```

Called like:

```
print(builder.getHashValue())
// Prints: -8479619369585612153
```

Obviously this hash changes each time the app is relaunched, so don't rely on it for persisting data.

And just for style reasons: you may prefer to use the following and make the classes just conform to `HashableBrand`:

```
typealias HashableBrand = Brand & Hashable
```

Comment: Oh! thank you very much!

Can we say that it is better to make the protocols as simple as possible and to add other conformance by extension with Self?

Comment: @bourvill The issue stems from the `Equatable` protocol (`==`) because of the `Self` requirement. `Hashable` conforms to `Equatable`. You won't usually encounter issues like this, but I know that there are Swift proposals going on you can see about things like having `any Hashable` for example to alleviate this issue. I wouldn't say the protocol needs to be as simple as possible - it's just that if the protocol relies on `Self` or an `associatedtype`, you can do this method of extending `Brand` **when** that thing that conforms to `Brand` is `Hashable`. Hope that made sense...?